# pagination for primary number of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, pagination

I'm still new at react and trying to make a pagination in react and it has a little flaw
I created the pagination by dividing data length / limit show data = total page.
but if my data is an odd number, i can't get the last data.
here's my code

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
contructor() {
 this.state = {
   data: [],
   page: 1,
   limit: 5,
   dataLength: '',
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.getData()
}

setPage(data) {
this.setState({ page: data },
() => {this.geData()}
 )
}
 setLimit(e) {
  this.setState({ limit: parseInt(e.target.value) },
  () => {this.getData()}
 )
}
getData(){
 axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `localhost:3000`,
})
.then((data) => {
  this.setState({
    data: data,
    dataLength: data.length
  });
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
 }
render() {
*let links= []
for (let i = 1; i <= (this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit); i++) 
{links.push(i)}*
  <select defaultValue='0' onChange={(e) => this.setLimit(e)}>
    <option disabled='true' value={0}>Select Limit Data</option>
    <option value={10}>10</option>
    <option value={50}>50</option>
    <option value={100}>100</option>
  </select>

 <h1>PAGE {this.state.page}</h1>
  *{ links.map((data, i) => {
 return <Button className='links' key={ i } onClick={() => 
 this.setPage(data)}> { data }</Button>
  }) }*
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: if your limit is 5, and you have data of length 53, you will need 11 pages (10 pages with 5 records, and the last one with 3).

But in your code you have this: `this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit`, which with the example numbers this will be `53/5 = 10.6` and which lead to 10 pages (1 will be missing).

So you will need to ceil the result of the division to make it work, because `ceil(10.6) = 11`. Just use `Math.ceil(this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit)` and it should work as expected

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
contructor() {
 this.state = {
   data: [],
   page: 1,
   limit: 5,
   dataLength: '',
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.getData()
}

setPage(data) {
this.setState({ page: data },
() => {this.geData()}
 )
}
 setLimit(e) {
  this.setState({ limit: parseInt(e.target.value) },
  () => {this.getData()}
 )
}
getData(){
 axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `localhost:3000`,
})
.then((data) => {
  this.setState({
    data: data,
    dataLength: data.length
  });
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
 }
render() {
*let links= []
for (let i = 1; i <= (Math.ceil(this.state.dataLength / this.state.limit)); i++) 
{links.push(i)}*
  <select defaultValue='0' onChange={(e) => this.setLimit(e)}>
    <option disabled='true' value={0}>Select Limit Data</option>
    <option value={10}>10</option>
    <option value={50}>50</option>
    <option value={100}>100</option>
  </select>

 <h1>PAGE {this.state.page}</h1>
  *{ links.map((data, i) => {
 return <Button className='links' key={ i } onClick={() => 
 this.setPage(data)}> { data }</Button>
  }) }*
}
```